# Cannot log property defined in inherited class

Tags: typescript

Here I have a `Tree` class that has a name prop, I was expecting that because `Evergreen` has `name` it would be logged, however this does not work.

```
class Tree {
  name?: string;
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

class Evergreen extends Tree {
  name = 'evergreen';
}

const x = new Evergreen(); // prints undefined
```

This works by redefining the constructor...

```
class Tree {
  name?: string;
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

class Evergreen extends Tree {
  name = 'evergreen';
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

const x = new Evergreen(); // undefined / evergreen
```

I'm trying to find a syntax that prevents the need for different constructors.

Ideally `super` was bound but this does not work.

```
class Tree {
  name?: string;
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

class Evergreen extends Tree {
  name = 'evergreen';
  constructor() {
    super.bind(this)();
  }
}

const x = new Evergreen();
```

Comment: This is very strange and interesting.  Obviously there are ways to restructure the code so that it's not an issue, but I can't give you any explanation about why it doesn't work now.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an issue at all. Because that's how OOP works. If you define a default value for a property in an inherited class then you can use it only in such class and its subclasses and not in any of the parent classes. Imagine that in the parent class will be logic that works with the default value of such property:

```
class Parent {
  name?: string;
  
  getNameLength(): string {
    return this.name.length; // It will gives you an error!
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  name = 'default';
}
```

or maybe like this:

```
class Parent {
  name: string; // It will gives you an error!
  
  getNameLength(): string {
    return this.name.length; // Yes, it will correct now
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  name = 'default';
}
```

If anyone will use this parent class without any inherited classes, how he can make sure that this parent class has an initializer for the default value?

TS and JS runtime, in this case, behaves absolutely correctly. You can't override this behavior.